# Load Json data multiple values in a column using pandas

Tags: json, pandas

My json file

```
{
  "Domain": "Hello",
  "Points": 0,
  "Search Name": "wonderful1 hello",
  "UserId": "wonder1",
  "UserName": "Wonderful1 Hello",
  "UserRole": "CONSUMER","CONS"
}
```

My code:

```
with open('e:\\data\\datafile.json') as f: 
    content = f.read()
df=pd.read_json('[' + content.replace('}\n', '},') + ']')
```

unable to load the into dataframe. If i get one more than one value in UserRole column. I was not able to load the data? Can you throw some lights on this?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. How do you expect it to be loaded in a dataframe?

Comment: remove "CONS" try ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `json.load` for convert json to `dict`s or list of dicts first:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

And then if necessary [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
  Domain  Points       Search Name   UserId          UserName  UserRole
0  Hello       0  wonderful1 hello  wonder1  Wonderful1 Hello  CONSUMER
```

Or if there is only one dictionary in data like in sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print (df)
  Domain  Points       Search Name   UserId          UserName  UserRole
0  Hello       0  wonderful1 hello  wonder1  Wonderful1 Hello  CONSUMER
```

Or if there are list of dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

EDIT:

Because not valid json file one possible solution is use `yaml.load`:

```
import yaml
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = yaml.load(data_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)  

print (data)
{'Domain': 'Hello', 'Points': 0, 'Search Name': 'wonderful1 hello',
 'UserId': 'wonder1', 'UserName': 'Wonderful1 Hello', 
 'UserRole': 'CONSUMER', 'CONS': None}

df = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
  Domain  Points       Search Name   UserId          UserName  UserRole  CONS
0  Hello       0  wonderful1 hello  wonder1  Wonderful1 Hello  CONSUMER  None
```

Comment: If i add two or more values in UserRole. I was not able to load. for example: "UserRole": "CONSUMER","CONS". How can i load the data into dataframe

Comment: @Gower - So json is not valid?

Comment: above mentioned code is working. but if i add one more value in Json file @ UserRole Column. I was not able to load in dataframe.  "UserRole": "CONSUMER","CONS"

Comment: @Gower - If invalid json file, not easy. Can you check if working solution in last paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try a very simple way

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json', 'r') as data_file:  
    content = data_file.read()

data = json.loads(content)
print(type(data)) # it should be a dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([data])
```

I've checked the code. It works well.

Comment: If remove `from_records` it is same like my answer (`from_records` is redundant here)

Comment: You're right. The difference is minor. Your solution should work.

Comment: Not working . getting error message Expecting ':' delimiter: line 8 column 1 (char 164)

Comment: Have you got a dictionary from your json?